# How to off throttle in debug=true?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

In Laravel in App/Http/Kernel exist such string:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

How to off throttle when debug mode in ENV set true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot set this dynamically as of now in Laravel.'

However what you can do is to define your own throttling middleware and then you can assign the throttle values dynamically.

Note: You can fetch the debug config like so:

```
config('app.debug')
```